# Separate objects and put them into pairs

Tags: python, string

So I have a variable `a` which contains:

```
WOOP:2,DERV:2,WHAT:2,MATE:1
```

And I would like to separate these so it would look like this:

```
[('WOOP',2),('DERV',2),('WHAT',2),('MATE',1)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one-liner would do it

```
L = [(f1, int(f2)) for x in a.split(",") for f1, f2 in (x.split(":"),)]
```

however I'd probably write instead

```
L = []
for x in a.split(","):
    f1, f2 = x.split(":")
    L.append((f1, int(f2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
l = [ tuple(s.split(':')) for s in a.split(',') ]
l = [ (t[0], int(t[1])) for t in l ]
```

If you are ok with `[['WOOP',2], ['DERV',2], ... ]`, then even simplier:

```
l = [ s.split(':') for s in a.split(',') ]
l = [ (t[0], int(t[1])) for t in l ]
```

Comment: PEP demands `s/ ([|])/\1/`. Also, you're not converting the second item to an int.

Comment: it works however, i want the number to stay as integer and not a string

Comment: Sorry, I missed int - see my updated answer. I was trying to come up with one-liner, but everything that comes to my mind is overly complicated or not optimal

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid doing this in one line:

```
>>> s = 'WOOP:2,DERV:2,WHAT:2,MATE:1'
>>> def convert_pair(pair):
...     word,number = pair.split(':')
...     return str(word),int(number)
... 
>>> [convert_pair(pair) for pair in s.split(',')]
[('WOOP', 2), ('DERV', 2), ('WHAT', 2), ('MATE', 1)]
```

Although I can't think of a better name for `convert_pair` at this time.

Comment: if that's the case, why not create another argument for the delimiter passed to split in `convert_pair`?

Answer (score 0):

If a is a string, you could use something like this:

```
result = map(lambda x: (x.split(":")[0], int(x.split(":")[1])), a.split(",")
```

If it's a dict, it's much simpler:

```
result = zip(a.keys(), a.values())
```

Hope this helps