# Python conversion from list to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a variable x (list)that looks like

```
['JACKIE:34', 'MATT:444', 'CEN:12', 'PETE:12', 'RANDY:92', 'MITCH:2', 'JAN:2']
```

which then i would like to convert to tuple (in pairs)so it would look like

```
[('JACKIE',34), ('MATT',444), ('CEN',12), ('PETE',12), ('RANDY',92), ('MITCH',2), ('JAN',2)]
```

Note that the number is an int.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separate objects and put them into pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526040/separate-objects-and-put-them-into-pairs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers as ints, as requested

```
before = ['JACKIE:34', 'MATT:444', 'CEN:12', 'PETE:12', 'RANDY:92', 'MITCH:2', 'JAN:2']
after = [(name, int(value)) for name, value in (x.split(':') for x in before)]
print after
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['JACKIE:34', 'MATT:444', 'CEN:12', 'PETE:12', 'RANDY:92', 'MITCH:2', 'JAN:2']
b = [x.split(':') for x in a]
b = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in b]
```